# add ctftime icon to my resume

Tags: symbols, fontawesome

Is it possible to add a [CTFtime](https://ctftime.org/) icon into a latex document? I've added previous social networks like this, but I'd like to know if I can add a flag or something like that.

.cls file:

```
\newcommand{\infofield}[2]{\mbox{\makebox[5mm]{\textcolor{accent}{\normalsize #1}}\hspace{0.5em}#2}\vspace{0.2em}\newline}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\infofield{\faEnvelope}{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\address}[1]{\infofield{\faAt}{#1}}
\newcommand{\location}[1]{\infofield{\faMapMarker}{#1}}
\newcommand{\phone}[1]{\infofield{\faPhone}{#1}}
\newcommand{\homepage}[2]{\infofield{\faHome}{\href{#2}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\linkedin}[2]{\infofield{\faLinkedin}{\href{#2}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\github}[2]{\infofield{\faGithub}{\href{#2}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\orcid}[2]{\infofield{\aiOrcid}{\href{#2}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ads}[2]{\infofield{\aiADS}{\href{#2}{#1}}}
```

.tex file:

```
    \section{Contact}
    
    \email{foo.foo@gmail.com}
    \phone{+52 811 1111111}
    \location{Some Street 1, 12345 City Name}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \github{@foo}{https://github.com/}
    \linkedin{Jhn doe}{some url}
```

The above code outputs the following icons.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify: what is CTFtime (I know the link but what is the relation of the contact details of you and CTFtime)? where do you get the flags?. Also, I smell that you have removed some code, please give us a short/dummy code of your resume or the document you successfully added contact detail icons [dummy: *Mia Khalifa* for names, *911* for numbers, *341, downtown, New York* for addresses.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy my bad, I've added a dummy code now. As it for CTFtime I just want to make a reference to my profile there because I play CTF (since my field is infosec). I mentioned the "flags" as a representative icon of the website. In fact the information of the contact its irrelevant, moreover, I'm trying to focus on the figures.

Comment: Very professional thought comment. Cheers! heads up: maybe others will ask to give a fully compilable, on-its-own MWE - I wont :)

Comment: OH! haven't anyone welcomed you? [Welcome to Tex.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you need to draw it by yourself. You could do this with Ti*k*Z, for example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, fontawesome, tikz, hyperref}

\newcommand{\infofield}[2]{%
  \makebox[20pt]{\textcolor{red}#1}#2%
}

\newcommand{\linkedin}[2]{\infofield{\faLinkedin}{\href{#2}{#1}}}

\newcommand{\myCtftime}{\tikz[y=1em, x=1em, baseline=1pt]{
  \path[fill, even odd rule] (0,0) -- (1.05,0) -- (1.05,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle
    (.15,.15) -- (.9,.15) -- (.9,.85) -- (.15,.85) -- cycle
    (.15,.85) -- (.35,.85) -- (.7,.5) -- (.45,.25) -- (.35,.35) -- (.5,.5) -- cycle; 
  }
}
\newcommand{\ctftime}[2]{\infofield{\myCtftime}{\href{#2}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\linkedin{John Doe}{https://linkedin.com/johndoe}

\ctftime{John Doe}{https://ctftime.org/johndoe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly